# $|x-a|=0.5$ $\times$ $x-1$ What is "a" if...?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value

a)the equation doesn't have solutions?

b)the equation has infinite number of solutions?

c)the equation has one solution?

d)the equation has only 2 solutions?

Could you please give more detailed explanations?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

No solution

[image]

One solution

[image]

Two solutions

[image]

What do you think about the situation of infinitely many solutions?

Credit to [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for the pictures.